# How do you exclude values when creating a string when setting up initial conditions?

Tags: r, string, if-statement, concatenation

I'm trying to combine columns in my data frame so that they give me a certain string. I have columns titled as "C", "H", "O", "N", and "S" as elements. Within those columns are listed the number of elements within that molecule, but I want to exclude some elements depending on their value. For example when there is no Oxygens the value is 0, so i want to exclude this when combining the elements to make a string.

```
#This is a portion of my data frame titled data4a
C H O N S
3 4 0 0 1
7 5 4 1 0

#The code I have is 
data4a$NewComp = paste("C",data4a$Total.C,"H", data4a$NewH, "O", data4a$O, "N", data4a$N, "S", data4a$S, sep = "")

#This code gives me this
C H O N S NewComp
3 4 0 0 1 C3H4O0N0S1
7 5 4 1 0 C7H5O4N1S0

#I expect to see something like this when I print my results
C H O N S NewComp
3 4 0 0 1 C3H4S1
7 5 4 1 0 C7H5O4N

#I want values of zero to be excluded from the string created
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is `apply` with argument `MARGIN = 1`

```
dat$NewComp <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) {
  tmp <- unlist(x)
  paste0(names(x)[tmp != 0], tmp[tmp != 0], collapse = "")
  })
```

Result

```
dat
#  C H O N S  NewComp
#1 3 4 0 0 1   C3H4S1
#2 7 5 4 1 0 C7H5O4N1
```

**data**

```
dat <- structure(list(C = c(3L, 7L), H = 4:5, O = c(0L, 4L), N = 0:1, 
    S = c(1L, 0L)), .Names = c("C", "H", "O", "N", "S"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: When running this code, it also combined my other columns that come before the elements. So i would need something in which I have to list what columns I want to combine.

Comment: Use `apply(dat[, c("C", "H", "O", "N", "S")], 1, function(x) ...` then.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution that solves the question problem and simplifies the creation of the molecule vectors at the same time.

```
m <- matrix(paste0(names(data4a), t(as.matrix(data4a))),
       ncol = ncol(data4a), byrow = TRUE)
m <- apply(m, 1, paste, collapse = "")
data4a$NewComp <- gsub(".0", "", m)

data4a
#  C H O N S  NewComp
#1 3 4 0 0 1   C3H4S1
#2 7 5 4 1 0 C7H5O4N1
```

**Data.**

```
data4a <- read.table(text = "
C H O N S
3 4 0 0 1
7 5 4 1 0
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: When running this code, it also combined my other columns that come before the elements. So i would need something in which I have to list what columns I want to combine.

Comment: @David Do those column names follow a pattern or do you know their numbers? You can have a vector `i_col <- c(3, 4, 6, 7)` and then always do `data4a[i_col]`. (except in the last code line, I'm talking about the other 3 occurrences of `data4a`.)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to use `which` and create a new dataframe with row number column number and value of the data which is not 0. We then replace the column number with column names and then use `aggregate` by row number to paste formula together.

```
df1 <- which(df != 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(df1, value = df[df != 0])
df2$col <- names(df)[df2$col]
df$NewComp <- aggregate(paste0(df2$col, df2$value), list(df2$row), 
               paste0, collapse = "")[, 2]

df
#  C H O N S  NewComp
#1 3 4 0 0 1   C3H4S1
#2 7 5 4 1 0 C7H5O4N1
```

As it has been mentioned in comments of other answer if you have data only in selected columns use `df[selected_columns]` in the first statement of `which`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility involving `tidyverse` could be:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -rowid) %>%
 filter(val != 0) %>%
 group_by(rowid) %>%
 summarise(NewComp = paste0(paste0(var, val), collapse = "")) %>%
 left_join(df %>%
            rowid_to_column(), by = c("rowid" = "rowid")) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rowid)

  NewComp      C     H     O     N     S
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 C3H4S1       3     4     0     0     1
2 C7H5O4N1     7     5     4     1     0
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -rowid) %>%
 filter(val != 0) %>%
 group_by(rowid) %>%
 mutate(NewComp = paste0(paste0(var, val), collapse = "")) %>%
 spread(var, val, fill = 0) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rowid)
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "C H O N S
3 4 0 0 1
                 7 5 4 1 0",
                 header = TRUE,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```